# Error launching Kentico 13 CMS on clean machine

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to run Kentico 13 CMS from source on a fresh machine but I'm getting this stack trace.  The site does not render the login prompt when I launch it with F5 from Visual Studio 2019.

I've restored a known good database to my local machine and confirmed that the site compiles successfully.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CMS.Membership.Internal.VirtualContextAuthenticationConfiguration.get_Audience()
   at CMS.Membership.Internal.SecurityTokenManager`1..ctor(T tokenConfiguration, IJwtTokenService tokenService, IDateTimeNowService dateTimeNowService, IEventLogService eventLogService, IUserInfoProvider userInfoProvider)
   at CMS.Membership.Internal.SecurityTokenManager`1..ctor(T tokenConfiguration)
   at Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.VirtualContextPrincipalRetriever..ctor()
   at Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.VirtualContextRequestPrincipalRetriever..ctor()
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.ContentOutputMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Kentico.Web.Mvc.KenticoRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Kentico.Content.Web.Mvc.PageRedirectionContextMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Kentico.Web.Mvc.KenticoRequestEventsMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was an incorrect database connection string.  I needed to confirm that the name of the database was correct, that the username and password were correct, and that the SQL Server instance had username/password authentication configured correctly (not just Windows auth).

Comment: Many thanks. Was adapting a .NET 5 Xperience application in my development environment I'd been running through IIS (and stopping/restarting every time I recompiled - so dumb). The problem was I'd been running the app pool as NT Authority/NetworkService which meant no creds in the connection string. Switched to a local SQL user for local dev.